# Concatenate files based on numeric sort of name substring in awk w/o header

Tags: bash, sorting, concatenation, ls

I am interested in concatenate many files together based on the numeric number and also remove the first line.

e.g. chr1_smallfiles then chr2_smallfiles then chr3_smallfiles.... etc (each without the header)

Note that `chr10_smallfiles` needs to come after `chr9_smallfiles` -- that is, this needs to be *numeric* sort order.

---

When separate the two command awk and ls -v1, each does the job properly, but when put them together, it doesn't work. Please help thanks!

```
awk 'FNR>1' | ls -v1 chr*_smallfiles > bigfile
```

Comment: remove every first line of the file?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `ls` here? Note that `ls` is a tool [only safe for interactive use](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); its output is not well-defined and machine-readable for the full range of possible filenames.

Comment: Also note that when you run `ls *.txt`, it isn't `ls` that takes the `*.txt` and transforms it to a list of individual filenames; the shell does that *before* it starts `ls`, so the actual command run is something like `ls one.txt two.txt three.txt`. Similarly, if you want to run `some_other_command one.txt two.txt three.txt` (when those three files are the only one with a name matching said pattern), you don't need `ls` -- you can just run `some_other_command *.txt`.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, how do you concatenate the files that's in the proper orders? like chr1, chr2, chr3.. etc, with the wildcard it's always sorted as 10, 11, 12,...,19, 1, 20, 21, 22,....

Comment: @Molly_K, ...added an answer that demonstrates one approach to establishing that ordering without `ls`. (Not the only approach -- another is to generate a NUL-delimited stream with the extracted key *before* each filename, sort that filename by the key, and then strip the leading keys off).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `tail` to concatenate all the files without header

```
tail -q -n+2 chr*_smallfiles > bigfile
```

In case you want to concatenate the files in a **natural sort order** as described in your quesition, you can pipe the result of `ls -v1` to `xargs` using

```
ls -v1 chr*_smallfiles | xargs -d $'\n' tail -q -n+2 > bigfile
```

(Thanks to Charles Duffy) `xargs -d $'\n'` sets the delimiter to a newline `\n` in case the filename contains white spaces or quote characters

Comment: Thanks @etopylight, but the concatenated file is not sorted in the order that I want. I would like to concatenate the files in the order of chr1, chr2, chr3 etc. With your method, it concatenates the files in the order of chr10, chr11, chr12.. chr19 then chr1 chr20, chr21, chr22, chr2 ... etc

Comment: @Molly_K Thanks for the comment, just updated my answer to support a predefined sort order.

Comment: `ls -v1` is still the wrong tool for the job -- particularly piping its output to `xargs`, a file named `foo bar` will result in two separate arguments, `foo` and `bar`, being passed out of xargs.

Comment: ...at minimum, make it `xargs -d $'\n'` to avoid string-splitting on whitespace, processing of literal quotes, etc. Or if you don't want to assume GNU xargs (but are willing to accept an extension also widespread in the BSD world), consider `... | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 ...`. Those still mishandle filenames with literal newlines, but at least not other whitespace or quote characters.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with the way that you're trying to pass the list of files to awk. At the moment, you're piping the output of awk to ls, which makes no sense.

Bear in mind that, as mentioned in the comments, ls is a tool for interactive use, and in general its output shouldn't be parsed.

If sorting weren't an issue, you could just use:

```
awk 'FNR > 1' chr*_smallfiles > bigfile
```

The shell will expand the glob `chr*_smallfiles` into a list of files, which are passed as arguments to awk. For each filename argument, all but the first line will be printed.

Since you want to sort the files, things aren't quite so simple. If you're sure the full range of files exist, just replace `chr*_smallfiles` with `chr{1..99}_smallfiles` in the original command.

---

Using some Bash-specific and GNU sort features, you can also achieve the sorting like this:

```
printf '%s\0' chr*_smallfiles | sort -z -n -k1.4 | xargs -0 awk 'FNR > 1' > bigfile
```

- `printf '%s\0'` prints each filename followed by a null-byte
- `sort -z` sorts records separated by null-bytes
- `-n -k1.4` does a numeric sort, starting from the 4th character (the numeric part of the filename)
- `xargs -0` passes the sorted, null-separated output as arguments to awk

---

Otherwise, if you want to go through the files in numerical order, and you're not sure whether all the files exist, then you can use a shell loop (although it'll be significantly slower than a single awk invocation):

```
for file in chr{1..99}_smallfiles; do # 99 is the maximum file number
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue # skip missing files
    awk 'FNR > 1' "$file"
done > bigfile
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, but the concatenated file is not sorted in the order that I want. That's why I used ls -v1 in the pipe. I would like to concatenate the files in the order of chr1, chr2, chr3 etc. With your method, it concatenates the files in the order of chr10, chr11, chr12.. chr19 then chr1 chr20, chr21, chr22, chr2 ... etc

Comment: If you know that all the files are there, a simple change would be to use `chr{1..99}_smallfiles` (where 99 is the last file), instead of the `*`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks very much! It works great! Thanks! Fortunately my files are just 50M each so it doesn't take that much more time. I really appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Using a bash 4 associative array to extract only the numeric substring of each filename; sort those individually; and then retrieve and concatenate the full names in the resulting order:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "Requires bash 4.0 or newer" >&2; exit 1;; esac

# when this is done, you'll have something like:
#   files=( [1]=chr_smallfiles1.txt
#           [10]=chr_smallfiles10.txt
#           [9]=chr_smallfiles9.txt )
declare -A files=( )
for f in chr*_smallfiles.txt; do
  files[${f//[![:digit:]]/}]=$f
done

# now, emit those indexes (1, 10, 9) to "sort -n -z" to sort them as numbers
# then read those numbers, look up the filenames associated, and pass to awk.
while read -r -d '' key; do
  awk 'FNR > 1' <"${files[$key]}"
done < <(printf '%s\0' "${!files[@]}" | sort -n -z) >bigfile
```

Comment: I think I found a simpler way to do the sorting (in my answer, in case you're interested).

Comment: @TomFenech, alas, I already upvoted your answer once, and can't do so again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do with a for loop like below, which is working for me:-

```
for file in chr*_smallfiles 
do
    tail +2 "$file" >> bigfile
done
```

How will it work? For loop read all the files from current directory with wild chard character `*` `chr*_smallfiles` and assign the file name to variable `file` and `tail +2 $file` will output all the lines of that file except the first line and append in file `bigfile`. So finally all files will be merged (accept the first line of each file) into one i.e. file `bigfile`.

Comment: You should quote your variables, and also move the `>>` outside of the loop to avoid repeatedly opening and closing the file.

Comment: You still can move the `>>`

Comment: @TomFenech, Not getting you can you give me an example? That will help. It works for me.

Comment: My answer contains an example with the redirection after the `done`.

Comment: This doesn't follow the OP's intent that the files be in numeric order without requiring padding (thus, that 10 be after 9). Which, granted, they weren't explicit about up-front.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, how about a `sed` solution?

```
for file in chr*_smallfiles 
    do
        sed -n '2,$p' $file >> bigfile
    done
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't follow the OP's intent that the files be in numeric order without requiring padding (thus, that 10 be after 9). Which, granted, they weren't explicit about up-front.